# how can I use reset_index with the multi grouped values(Hierarchical format) in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

[image]

this is my data format, I want to reset the index and wanna make it in one table format, so I can take the count of all the id's which is 2nd row and can plot them with the histogram by date and the count,

any simple idea?

Comment: what you mean by the get_level_index(-1) here and how it will take the value_count of the 2nd column which is Index

Comment: What is the output of `df.reset_index()`? Please post code and data directly as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: df.reset_index is not working here, I tried it, that's why I posted here
my code is

`grouping= HistData.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('2H'), 'ID1, 'ID2'])
grouper = grouping['ID1'].count()
type(grouper)
`

Comment: @Ravi Please post an example data that reproduces your problem. Not screenshot.

Comment: I posted the data in the Answer box, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

if `reset_index()` is not working, you can convert the table manually also.
Assume df1 is your existing data frame, we'll create df2 (new one) that you want.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2['DateTime'] = df1.index.get_level_values(0).tolist()
df2['ID1'] = df1.index.get_level_values(1).tolist()
df2['ID2'] = df1['ID2'].values.tolist()
df2['Count'] = df1['Count'].values.tolist()
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, but df1 is not the dataframe again so I does not select the column from that list, as you mentioned.

Comment: Then what is the type of df1 ?

Comment: I checked it with the type(df1) it tells me the Pandas series.Series, but I am not sure why it is unable to select the columns.. with `df1['ID1']` I am still looking for the issue what's going on.